# Missing HLSL Debug Symbols with D3Dcompile in Visual Studio

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, hlsl, direct3d

I have an application that works as expected by clearing the screen and drawing a triangle, but I want to step through the vertex and pixel shader code in the visual studio graphics debugger, but the debug symbols seem to be missing:

[image]

I'm using VS2022 version 17.9.4, and the shaders are read from source and compiled at runtime using D3DCompile with the following flags:

```
D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION | D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS
```

Any ideas on what could be missing? The option to enable the gathering of GPU disassembly doesn't seem to be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like pressing F10 does allow me to step through the code and see the local variables change, just can't place a breakpoint.

Comment: Please close the issue if you find the answer by yourself